# Is there possible, increment variable without plus sign in javascript?

Tags: javascript, increment

When I put the javascript code In my WordPress plugin then from the code all **+ signs** are removed by the plugin.
And I see the errors on screen. What do I do?

Actually, I already did this with PHP but I don't know how I have done in javascript.

This is my PHP code.

```
function increment($i) 
{ 
    // Invert bits and  
    // apply negative sign 
    $i = -(~$i); 
  
    return $i; 
} 
  
// Driver code 
$n = 3; 
echo increment($n);
```

Actually, I want to try increment without **+ sign**.

## Edit:

While this question may seem silly, the problem originates from url-encoding/decoding the javascript code, which replaces `+` with `space`. This is also annoying when developing bookmarklets, which is Javascript code stored as URLs.

The answer to simply subtract the negated value is however the most straightforward solution.

Comment: The same trick works in JS. `-(~i)`

Comment: You should probably look at the specifics of that plugin instead, this is a somewhat ludicrous question…

Comment: As deceze inferred, this probably won't fix your problem

Comment: What about minus sign? `$i- -1` :)

Comment: Only about `+` sign not `-` @YuryTarabanko

Comment: @shamshertechnical Anyways agreed to deceze the plugin behaviour is strange. The question is [The XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Actually, I am using the free version of the plugin so I use Javascript for an alternate of pro features  @deceze

Comment: Actually, I am using the free version of the plugin so I use Javascript for an alternate of pro features @JuanMendes

Comment: Means is it not Possible.@YuryTarabanko

Comment: That means you are trying to hack around a restriction of the free product, you are likely breaking their terms of use

Comment: XY problem. If the plugin expects url encoded data, use `i%20%2B%3D%201`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should really consider understanding how your plugin works because it is a very silly behavior.

Anyway, just for fun, you can use double `minus` sign to achieve what you want:

```
let a = 10
let b = a - (-17) // b = 27
```

You can also create a function:

```
function add(a, b) {
  return a - (-b);
}
for (var i = 0; i < b.length; add(i, 1)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I just want to apply in this code.

`for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {`

Comment: @shamshertechnical `i-=(-1)`